# SQL Query Optimisation for multiple table jons with millions of records

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone suggest me a way to optimise the given query? It has multiple joins and if we try it with larger dataset of 10M records. The query takes much amount of time.

```
SELECT 
    AUDM.distributeTS AS distributionDate,
    ASMT.name,
    ACM.studentid,
    AUDM.users AS distributedTo,
    ROUND(AUM.totaluser * 100 / AUDM.users) AS participation,
    ROUND(AUM.score * 5 / (AUM.totaluser * AQM.qi)) AS performance
FROM
    (SELECT 
        name, assessmentId
    FROM
        Assessment
    WHERE
        type IN ('PSYCHOMETRIC' , 'QUANTITATIVE', '')
            AND removed = FALSE) ASMT
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        studentid, assessmentId
    FROM
        AssessmentCreatorMap) ACM ON ACM.assessmentId = ASMT.AssessmentId
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        assessmentId, COUNT(assessmentId) AS qi
    FROM
        AssessmentQuestionMap
    GROUP BY assessmentId) AQM ON AQM.assessmentId = ASMT.assessmentId
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
         COUNT(userId) AS users, distributeTS, assessmentId
    FROM
        AssessmentUserDistributeMap 
    GROUP BY assessmentId) AUDM ON AUDM.assessmentId = ASMT.assessmentId
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        assessmentId,
            COUNT(assessmentId) AS totaluser,
            SUM(assessmentScore) AS score
    FROM
        AssessmentUserMap
    JOIN Student ON AssessmentUserMap.studentId = Student.studentid
    WHERE
        enrollmentDate IS NOT NULL
            AND isDeleted = FALSE
    GROUP BY assessmentId) AUM ON AUM.assessmentId = ASMT.assessmentId
ORDER BY ASMT.AssessmentId DESC
LIMIT 0 , 15;
```

explain yields the following result.

```
'1', 'PRIMARY', 'Assessment', NULL, 'index', NULL, 'PRIMARY', '4', NULL, '1', '5.00', 'Using where; Backward index scan'
'1', 'PRIMARY', 'AssessmentCreatorMap', NULL, 'ref', 'fk_AssessmentCreatorMap_aid_idx', 'fk_AssessmentCreatorMap_aid_idx', '5', 'OustMe_UAT.Assessment.AssessmentId', '1', '100.00', NULL
'1', 'PRIMARY', '<derived4>', NULL, 'ref', '<auto_key0>', '<auto_key0>', '5', 'OustMe_UAT.Assessment.AssessmentId', '10', '100.00', NULL
'1', 'PRIMARY', '<derived5>', NULL, 'ref', '<auto_key0>', '<auto_key0>', '5', 'OustMe_UAT.Assessment.AssessmentId', '601', '100.00', NULL
'1', 'PRIMARY', '<derived6>', NULL, 'ref', '<auto_key0>', '<auto_key0>', '5', 'OustMe_UAT.Assessment.AssessmentId', '10', '100.00', NULL
'6', 'DERIVED', 'AssessmentUserMap', NULL, 'ALL', 'fk_AssessmentUserMap_assessmentid_idx,fk_aum_studentid,idx_AssessmentUserMap_assessmentId_enrollmentDate,idx_AssessmentUserMap_assessmentId_studentid', NULL, NULL, NULL, '1055', '90.00', 'Using where; Using temporary'
'6', 'DERIVED', 'Student', NULL, 'eq_ref', 'studentid_UNIQUE,idx_Student_studentid,fk_student_isdel', 'studentid_UNIQUE', '182', 'OustMe_UAT.AssessmentUserMap.studentid', '1', '50.00', 'Using index condition; Using where'
'5', 'DERIVED', 'AssessmentUserDistributeMap', NULL, 'index', 'fk_AssessmentUserDistributeMap_aid_idx,idx_AssessmentUserDistributeMap_assessmentId_userId,idx_assessmentUserDistributeMap_userId_assessmentId', 'fk_AssessmentUserDistributeMap_aid_idx', '5', NULL, '397282', '100.00', NULL
'4', 'DERIVED', 'AssessmentQuestionMap', NULL, 'index', 'fk_AssessmentQuestionMap_aid_idx', 'fk_AssessmentQuestionMap_aid_idx', '5', NULL, '3308', '100.00', 'Using index'
```

most of the tables have the indexes already . Please comment if there is any need to add a new index or how can we rewrite the query to produce the same resultset.

Answer (score 1):

The query is using too many **left join** and from my experience it's very slow. Try avoiding it.

Solution for your problem is doing filter before you doing any grouping for any table.

you can get and save assessmentId from below query

```
    with x as (   SELECT name, assessmentId
    FROM   Assessment
    WHERE
    type IN ('PSYCHOMETRIC' , 'QUANTITATIVE', '')
    AND removed = FALSE);

    SELECT 
    COUNT(userId) AS users, distributeTS, assessmentId
    FROM
    AssessmentUserDistributeMap 
    where assessmentId in (select assessmentId from x) -- add this block in every your grouping
    GROUP BY assessmentId
```

updated query:

```
    WITH ASMT as (SELECT name, assessmentId
        FROM  Assessment
        WHERE type IN ('PSYCHOMETRIC' , 'QUANTITATIVE', '')
        AND removed = FALSE)            
    SELECT 
        AUDM.distributeTS AS distributionDate,
        ASMT.name,
        ACM.studentid,
        AUDM.users AS distributedTo,
        ROUND(AUM.totaluser * 100 / AUDM.users) AS participation,
        ROUND(AUM.score * 5 / (AUM.totaluser * AQM.qi)) AS performance
    FROM ASMT
        LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT studentid, assessmentId
        FROM AssessmentCreatorMap Where assessmentId in (select assessmentId from ASMT)) ACM ON ACM.assessmentId = ASMT.AssessmentId
        LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT assessmentId, COUNT(assessmentId) AS qi
        FROM AssessmentQuestionMap  Where assessmentId in (select assessmentId from ASMT)
        GROUP BY assessmentId) AQM ON AQM.assessmentId = ASMT.assessmentId
        LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT COUNT(userId) AS users, distributeTS, assessmentId
        FROM AssessmentUserDistributeMap Where assessmentId in (select assessmentId from ASMT)
        GROUP BY assessmentId) AUDM ON AUDM.assessmentId = ASMT.assessmentId
        LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT assessmentId, COUNT(assessmentId) AS totaluser, SUM(assessmentScore) AS score
        FROM AssessmentUserMap
        JOIN Student ON AssessmentUserMap.studentId = Student.studentid
        WHERE enrollmentDate IS NOT NULL 
        AND isDeleted = FALSE
        and assessmentId in (select assessmentId from ASMT)
        GROUP BY assessmentId) AUM ON AUM.assessmentId = ASMT.assessmentId
    ORDER BY ASMT.AssessmentId DESC
    LIMIT 0 , 15;
```

Below query will calculate all data on table AssessmentQuestionMap, even though we will not using all the result data, because there's will be filter by **ON** clause, let say there's 10000 record data on table **AssessmentQuestionMap**, it's not efficient to do all the calculation, that's why we put the filter before any grouping calculation on the query

```
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT assessmentId, COUNT(assessmentId) AS qi
    FROM AssessmentQuestionMap
    GROUP BY assessmentId) AQM
```

Add the filter before grouping

```
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT assessmentId, COUNT(assessmentId) AS qi
    FROM AssessmentQuestionMap  Where assessmentId in (select assessmentId from ASMT)
    GROUP BY assessmentId) AQM ON AQM.assessmentId = ASMT.assessmentId
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by moving the first two tables away from being 'derived' tables ('subqueries in FROM or JOIN').  Keep the derived tables with aggregates (`COUNT...GROUP BY`).

```
SELECT  AUDM.distributeTS AS distributionDate, ASMT.name, ACM.studentid,
        AUDM.users AS distributedTo, ROUND(AUM.totaluser * 100 / AUDM.users) AS participation,
        ROUND(AUM.score * 5 / (AUM.totaluser * AQM.qi)) AS performance
    FROM  Assessment AS ASMT
    JOIN  AssessmentCreatorMap AS ACM  ON ACM.assessmentId = ASMT.AssessmentId 
    LEFT JOIN  
    (
        SELECT  assessmentId, COUNT(*) AS qi
            FROM  AssessmentQuestionMap
            GROUP BY  assessmentId
    ) AQM  ON AQM.assessmentId = ASMT.assessmentId
    LEFT JOIN  
    (
        SELECT  COUNT(*) AS users, distributeTS, assessmentId
            FROM  AssessmentUserDistributeMap
            GROUP BY  assessmentId
    ) AUDM  ON AUDM.assessmentId = ASMT.assessmentId
    LEFT JOIN  
    (
        SELECT  assessmentId, COUNT(*) AS totaluser, SUM(assessmentScore) AS score
            FROM  AssessmentUserMap
            JOIN  Student  ON AssessmentUserMap.studentId = Student.studentid
            WHERE  enrollmentDate IS NOT NULL
              AND  isDeleted = FALSE
            GROUP BY  assessmentId
    ) AUM  ON AUM.assessmentId = ASMT.assessmentId
    WHERE  ASMT.type IN ('PSYCHOMETRIC' , 'QUANTITATIVE', '')
      AND  ASMT.removed = FALSE
     ORDER BY  ASMT.AssessmentId DESC
    LIMIT  0 , 15;
```

Then, some of these indexes may help:

```
AUDM:  INDEX(assessmentId,  distributeTS, users)
ASMT:  INDEX(removed, type,  name, assessmentId)
ACM:  INDEX(assessmentId,  studentid)
AUM:  INDEX(assessmentId,  totaluser, score)
AQM:  INDEX(assessmentId,  qi)
AssessmentUserMap:  INDEX(studentId)
Student:  INDEX(studentid)
```

Also, avoid using `COUNT(x)` if unless the goal is to count only rows with `x IS NOT NULL`.  Normally, it is better to "count rows" via `COUNT(*)`.  (I made those changes; change them back if necessary.)

It is not possible to avoid a temp table and sort.  This is because the `IN` has multiple items.  (A really messy `UNION` could avoid that issue.)

My index suggestions is incomplete because I don't know which tables the various columns are in in the last join.